# codeigniter : Why does the requested page is not found?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, http-status-code-404

i have link like this

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/c_materialjasa/gkategorimaterial">Lihat Tabel</a></td>
```

here is my controller

```
  class C_kategorimaterial extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('m_materialjasa');
    $this->load->model('m_admin');
}
function gkategorimaterial()
{
    //$data['title'] = 'Ambil Kode Kategori Material Jasa';
    //$this->load->view('head',$data);
    //$this->load->view('g/gkategorimaterial');

    echo 'getkategorimaterial';


}}
```

and the screen display error `404 not found` ? i have created the views `gkategorimaterial` it located on views/g/gkategorimaterial

Comment: Is the view named `gkategorimaterial.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller name has to come before the function name:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/
           c_kategorimaterial/gkategorimaterial">Lihat Tabel</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved ! i was copy pasting Controller A into -> Controller B, then i forgot to change its class into Controller B extends somekindlikethat

Thank You